# Variable value changing after returning from a function in C

Tags: c, variables, matrix

I've been coding for my university where we are working with matrices and I can't find the error in the code that is changing the value of the variable where I save the columns of the matrix. I've tried debugging it and can´t find it, it simply ends the function where I allocate the memory por the matrix and enters the next function (which gets values from keyboard to fill the matrix) with the wrong column value. 
The code is the next:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEBUG 1

void allocate (int ***mat,int n,int m){
    int i;
    *mat = (int **) malloc (n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        mat[i] = (int *) malloc (m*sizeof(int));
    }
    #if DEBUG
        printf ("allocate n: %d m: %d\n",n,m);
    #endif // DEBUG
}

void initialize (int **mat, int n, int m){
    int i,j;
    #if DEBUG
        printf ("initialize n: %d m: %d\n",n,m);
    #endif // DEBUG
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<m; j++){
            printf ("Enter value for position [%d][%d]: ",i,j);
            scanf ("%d",&(mat[i][j]));
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
        int n=2;
        int m=3;
        int **mat=NULL;
        #if DEBUG
            printf ("before allocate n: %d m: %d\n",n,m);
        #endif // DEBUG
        allocate (&mat,n,m);
         #if DEBUG
            printf ("after allocate n: %d m: %d\n",n,m);
        #endif // DEBUG
        initialize (mat,n,m);
        return 0;
}
```

So if you run this with DEBUG set to 1 you will get the values of n and m (which are my rows and columns). I am using codeblocks. 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: Post code that actually compiles. Fix warnings, too.

Comment: You need to change your allocation to `(*mat)[i] = (int *) malloc (m*sizeof(int));`

Comment: @ooga: Yes, he does. But that cannot cause the problem he is talking about because that simply doesn't compile.

Comment: After making it compile (fixing the allocation, a spelling error in the function call to `initialize` and missing semicolons), the code works for me and I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: @ooga changing that line fixed the problem, don't know why though, as it compiled and did great at receiveing values for the matrix if i changed the value of m before initialize line. Thanks!

Comment: @MacuDuranti: If that line compiled, I'd seriously consider switching to another compiler or change your compilation options. That's dangerous.

Comment: @mastov Yes it works now, but if you don't fix the allocation it does what I said!. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @mastov ok thanks, which compiler do you recommend?

Comment: In case you are unaware, you can use `int (*mat)[m] = malloc(n * sizeof *mat);` instead of `int **mat; allocate(&mat, n, m);`, and the initialize function would be `void initialize (int n, int m, int mat[n][m])`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes thanks!, Its just that we were asked to make a function that allocated the memory. Didn't know about `int (*mat)[m]` though.

Comment: You could make a function that just calls malloc and returns ..:)

Comment: Great example. Beside accepted solution one can use `*(*mat+i) = malloc (m*sizeof(int));` and `*(mat[0]+i) = malloc (m*sizeof(int));` and `mat[0][i] = malloc (m*sizeof(int));`. Will you cast to `(int*)` or `(int**)` does not really make difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the function

```
void allocate( int ***mat, int n, int m )
{
    int i;

    *mat = (int **) malloc( n * sizeof( int* ) );
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        ( *mat )[i] = ( int *) malloc ( m * sizeof( int ) );
    }
    #if DEBUG
        printf ("allocate n: %d m: %d\n",n,m);
    #endif // DEBUG
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d3cb5ed16ae73a5

```
void allocate (int ***mat,int n,int m){
    int i;
    *mat = (int **) malloc (n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        //This is where the error is.
        (*mat)[i] = (int *) malloc (m*sizeof(int));
    }
    #if DEBUG
        printf ("allocate n: %d m: %d\n",n,m);
    #endif // DEBUG
}
```

You see, you didn't actually reference a specific cell in the array with `mat[i]`. No, you actually referenced the pointer to the matrix and then indexed to a column or row, which means you allocated memory for `int*`, not an `int`.

Thus, you need to deference the original matrix pointer to the matrix, and then index -> `(mat*)[i]`.